# A problem about the existence of some function in a functional space

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $x\in X\subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $g_{i}(x)$ ($i=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$) be a set of functions in $L^{1}(X,P)$, 
where $P$ is the probability measure (atomless). Suppose that the functional

$$\int g_{i}(x)\:\mathrm{d}P  \qquad i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$$

are linearly independent. Suppose that $0≤h_{0}(x)≤\varepsilon$ is a known function for a sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$, such that:

$$\int g_{i}(x)h_{0}(x)\:\mathrm{d}P≠0.$$

We want to know, whether there exists any uniformly bounded function $0≤h(x)≤h$ such that

$$\int_{a}^{b}g_{i}(x)h(x)\:\mathrm{d}P=\int g_{i}(x)h_{0}(x)\:\mathrm{d}P  \qquad i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\},$$

for any interval $[a,b]\subset X$ such that $P(x\in[a,b])≥\delta>0$ and $\int_{a}^{b}g_{i}(x)\:\mathrm{d}P$ are linearly independent.
    The case $n=1$ is easy. I am kind of able to show $n=2$. But the case $n=3$ is messy... any idea? Thank you!